# only update titles of single posts

Tags: functions, filters

The below function wraps all titles of all pages in a * symbol. I want to change the function so that it only applies the filter to titles of single posts. How can I accomplish this?

```
function apply_titles($title, $id)  {
     return "* ".$title." *";
     return $title;
}

add_filter('the_title', 'apply_titles', 10, 2);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to wrap post title of posts only, then you should use `get_post_type()` to check post type of post. You can take reference from below code, it will applied on "post" post type only. and want to apply on  post single page then you have to add `is_single()`  with `get_post_type()` condition.

```
function apply_titles($title, $id)  {
     if('post' == get_post_type($id) && is_single())
     {
        return "* ".$title." *";
     }
     return $title;
}
add_filter('the_title', 'apply_titles', 10, 2);
```

Comment: thanks Chetan ! the if statement does the job.